# How to check if a array is even or odd php

Tags: php

I have an array and I need to find if the values are even or odd and print them.

```php
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
```

And I print the results in array format (I`m looking to use "echo" to print each)

I found a solution that is to create a while loop and use modules `%2`
like:

```php
$foreach ($numbers % 2==0) {  //even
  echo "value is even";
} else {
  echo "value is odd";
}
```

But it doesnt work, and i only have experience working with numbers in if statements and loops. How would i go about this when working with an array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been to php.net? They have documentation about every function they've created.

Comment: No, i will head over there now.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

```php
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
foreach ($numbers as $n) {
    echo 'value '. $n .' is: ';
    echo  ($n % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo "\n"; // optional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try also like this, this is more understandable for you**

```
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

    foreach($numbers as $value)
    {
      if($value%2==0)
      {
        echo $value 'is even <br/>';
      }
      else
      {
        echo $value 'is odd <br/>';
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code,

You are in `right direction` but there will be a little bit of change in your code i.e. you are applying condition on ***whole array*** which is ***wrong*** you have to ***fetch single value*** and apply ***even number condition.***

```
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

foreach($numbers as $var)
{
  if($var%2==0)
  {
    echo $var;
  }
  else
  {
    echo $var;
  }

}
```